# Can a 21.5 inch iMac (non-Retina late 2015 - 2.8 Ghz, Intel Iris Pro graphics, model 16,2) drive two external displays?

Tags: display, imac, thunderbolt, resolution, displayport

I'm currently running a Dell U2715H at its native resolution (2560 x 1440) via DisplayPort as an external display, and I'd like to add another at that same resolution. The [Apple specs](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP733?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) on this model don't say anything about two external displays.

Is it possible to run two external displays with this model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bit the bullet and bought another DisplayPort monitor (Dell U2414H), and sure enough, it works out of the box! I'm currently running a total of three displays - the iMac built in at 1920x1200, the 24" Dell at 1920x1200, and the 27" Dell at 2560x1440.

Answer (score 2):

Not according to [EveryMac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-i5-2.8-21-inch-aluminum-late-2015-specs.html) who are usually spot on with their info, including unsupported 'hacks', none of which are mentioned for this model.

> This model can simultaneously support the internal display at full native resolution and up to 4096x2304 on an external display in both extended desktop (second workspace) and video mirroring (internal display duplicated on the external display) modes.

Comment: I saw the EveryMac page, but it essentially said the same as the Apple specs page. I find it curious that a 13" Macbook Pro has the power to run two displays (albeit maybe not at 2560 x 1440), but the iMac can't. Additionally, most of the Apple specs list a total supported resolution across all external displays, which in this case could mean two 1080p displays.

Comment: Then empiricism is your next move. First, see how many ports it has...

Comment: The iMac has two Thunderbolt ports, and the support page lists a total supported resolution of 4096 by 2304, so in theory it should support at least two 1080p monitors. But I haven't been able to find anything definitively confirming or denying that this is the case, hence my hesitation at pulling the trigger on a 2nd monitor. :)

Comment: Then borrow one ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can run 2 displays

If you have an iPad pro

iPad

iPad Air 1/2

There's an app called duet display

11.99 GBP

Then a free download from duetdisplay.com to install the app on this model of iMac

Turn off iTunes backup to save space

Open the app on iMac

Connect lightning or 30 pin from usb on iMac to iPad model

Open app on iPad model

Et voila

2 displays

Not only do you have 2 displays but you also get lag free touch controls on your iOS device

It is very good

Check it out on your dell

It works with Windows too

All you need is an iPad lol